# Passing several values with AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This isn't working:

```
$.ajax({url: "PStoreZoomArea.php", type: "get", data: {"mapza": mapZoomArea, "mapc": mapCenter, "mapz": mapZoom}})
```

The code in the PHP-file:

```
$_SESSION['mapZoomArea'] = (isset($_GET['mapza']) ? $_GET['mapza'] : '1');
$_SESSION['mapCenter'] = (isset($_GET['mapc']) ? $_GET['mapc'] : '(55.67893946343211, 12.568359375)');
$_SESSION['mapZoom'] = (isset($_GET['mapz']) ? $_GET['mapz'] : '11');
```

If I only send one value it's working, but not with several. I have also tested to use a AJAX call for each value, but not working either. What could be wrong?

Comment: Where does `$.ajax` come from? Some library that you are using?

Comment: What does `print_r($_GET)` output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using GET, change your ajax block to this instead:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "PStoreZoomArea.php", 
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "text",
  data: "mapza=" + mapZoomArea + "&mapc=" + mapCenter + "&mapz=" + mapZoom
});
```

Check out JQuery's official documentation on .ajax

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: `data` may be either string (as in your example) or object with key/value pairs (as in author's example). Object seems to be more readable.

Comment: The object is more readable and more reliable -- if you have unsafe characters, they'll be encoded if you put them in an object, but won't be if you put them in a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
 url: "PStoreZoomArea.php", 
 type: "GET", 
 data: {"mapza": mapZoomArea, 
  "mapc": mapCenter, 
  "mapz": mapZoom
 }
});
```

and your php code needs to be either what you have already or instead of GET use REQUEST also look in firebugs console what the request looks like to make sure it hits the correct php script and all the parameters are displaying

```
$_SESSION['mapZoomArea'] = (isset($_REQUEST['mapza']) ? $_REQUEST['mapza'] : '1');
$_SESSION['mapCenter'] = (isset($_REQUEST['mapc']) ? $_REQUEST['mapc'] : '(55.67893946343211, 12.568359375)');
$_SESSION['mapZoom'] = (isset($_REQUEST['mapz']) ? $_REQUEST['mapz'] : '11');
```